# How can I use one field as a replacement value for multiple fields?

Tags: sql, sql-server, coalesce

Below is an example output from a SQL query I'm working on (I can't share for confidentiality reasons). My issue is I'm needing the column "L4" to replace the first NULL in each row and no other nulls in that row. My current approach is using COALESCE() but doesn't work (see below):

`COALESCE(L3, L2, L1, L4) as L1,`
`COALESCE(L3, L2, L4) as L2,`
`COALESCE(L3, L4) as L3`

Any idea if there is a way to do this in SQL?

| Row # | L1 | L2 | L3 | L4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mike | NULL | NULL | Anne |
| 2 | Joe | Mark | NULL | James |
| 3 | NULL | NULL | NULL | Bob |
| 4 | Andrew | John | Tom | Matt |
| 5 | Joe | NULL | NULL | Mark |

Expected output:

| Row # | L1 | L2 | L3 | L4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mike | Anne | NULL | Anne |
| 2 | Joe | Mark | James | James |
| 3 | Bob | NULL | NULL | Bob |
| 4 | Andrew | John | Tom | Matt |
| 5 | Joe | Mark | NULL | Mark |

Comment: Please also include the expected output you want.

Comment: By field you mean column I assume?

Comment: @DaleK - Yes, I do mean column. These are all fields in a data set which is why I mixed the terms.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have edited to show what I'm wanting as far as output

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use some CASE statements in your query to achieve this?

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN (L1 IS NULL) THEN L4 ELSE L1 END AS L1r,
CASE WHEN (L1 IS NOT NULL AND L2 IS NULL) THEN L4 ELSE L2 END AS L2r,
CASE WHEN (L1 IS NOT NULL AND L2 IS NOT NULL AND L3 IS NULL) THEN L4 ELSE L3 END AS L3r
FROM Table
```

Comment: Case *expression* not *statement* :)